# Up to which value is Rassias' conjecture verified?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, open-problem

I came across this conjecture:

[Rassias' conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rassias%27_conjecture)

> Up to which $p$ has this conjecture be verified ?
>
> Are there intermediate results related to this conjecture ?

The conjecture can be formulated in this way :

> For every prime $p>2$, there is a prime $q$, such that $(p-1)q-1$ is prime.

The following PARI/GP-program shows, that for every $p$ with $2<p<10^8$, there is a prime $q\le 1187$ doing the job.

```
? maxi=0;p=2;while(p<10^8,p=nextprime(p+1);q=1;gef=0;while(gef==0,q=nextprime(q+
1);u=(p-1)*q-1;if(isprime(u)==1,gef=1;if(q>maxi,maxi=q;print(p,"  ",q,"   ",u)))
))
3  2   3
19  3   53
73  5   359
109  11   1187
139  19   2621
179  23   4093
467  29   13513
1229  71   87187
2447  83   203017
2819  269   758041
8699  281   2444137
24419  311   7593997
57977  443   25683367
266117  503   133856347
374399  641   239989117
711089  653   464340463
4099493  719   2947534747
4313873  821   3541688911
8466209  881   7458729247
13187129  1031   13595928967
52172843  1187   61929163453
?
```

> Update : The conjectrue remains true for $2<p<10^9$ and a prime $q\le 1709$
>   does the job in that range.

```
? while(p<10^9,p=nextprime(p+1);q=1;gef=0;while(gef==0,q=nextprime(q+1);u=(p-1)*
q-1;if(isprime(u)==1,gef=1;if(q>maxi,maxi=q;print(p,"  ",q,"   ",u)))))
103784147  1193   123814486177
112564253  1361   153199946971
174454277  1367   238478995291
280721033  1511   424169479351
623020787  1613   1004932527817
855177437  1697   1451236108891
929408729  1709   1588359516151
?
```

Comment: There are so many conjectures in Number Theory and this is one of them.It is a mix of well known open problems with an extra restriction in addition.It belongs to "Conjectural number theory".I don't understand why you care at all...

Comment: Rassias' conjecture is somewhat stronger than Dirichlet's theorem. It is clear, that there are infinite many primes of the form $(p-1)k-1$ for every prime $p>2$, and it is very likely that the sequence of $k's$, for which $(p-1)k-1$ is prime, contains a prime. The conjecture is true for $2<p<10^9$ and in that range, there is always a prime $q\le 1709$ doing the job.

Comment: I don't know if there are intermediate results, or a good approach to attack the conjecture, due my knowledges. My idea is try to combine with theorems or other conjectures to get new conjectures from a huge computational evidence. Example: If you invoke Bredihin's theorem that is cited in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294352/primes-of-the-form-x2-y2-1) then on assumption of Rassias' conjecture should be infinitely many solutions of $p_1(x^2+y^2)=1+p_2$ with $p_1<p_2$ prime numbers and $x,y\geq 1$ integers. Maybe is interesting to study the frecuency of such examples.